# React-redux with re-base-firebase. Good idea?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm building a small Firebase app with React as the view. I have been working with Redux a lot recently, so I thought I'd use it here too.

BUT, it seems that [Flux architecture and Firebase are at odds](https://twitter.com/tylermcginnis33/status/605838057825132549) and libraries like [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) are based on trying to avoid those conflicts, which I understand.

However it's unclear to me, given that Flux and Redux are fairly different, what is the simplest option:

1. use Redux-react and Firebase
2. use Redux-react and re-base
3. forget REdux; just use React and re-base
4. use React and Firebase

Anyone with experience in this that can advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering about this myself. There are some examples of react-redux and Firebase: [Functioning demo](https://github.com/vkammerer/react-redux-firebase)

But there is also [ReactFire](https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) referenced from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/) as the "official" framework integration.

Comment: The problem with react-fire is that is uses mixins, i.e. it's not ES6 compatible. That's why I have been looking at [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base). However since Firebase has gone through a major upgrade recently all libraries are a bit redundant. https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base/issues/99

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in an ES6 compatible react-redux library, there is [react-redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase). There is a [short medium article](https://medium.com/@prescottprue/firebase-with-redux-82d04f8675b9) I [mention in the FAQ](http://react-redux-firebase.com/#faq) about why linking Firebase state and redux state is nice, but it seems like that is what you are already trying to do.

My experience with react, redux, and Firebase has lead me to decide that combining the state does have its merits. This becomes especially true when dealing with auth and user profiles.

**Disclosure**:

I am the author of react-redux-firebase (the library mentioned above) and the medium article mentioned.